# Scaling and rotating images in C# results in ghosted edges

Tags: c#, .net, image, system.drawing

I'm using C# to scale and rotate an image with a transparent background, then using JavaScript to add it to a Google Maps API map, but once it's scaled and rotated, the edges of the image get blurred, and it becomes hard to see, especially over water.

Here is my original 300x300 image:

[image: Here is my original 300x300 image.]

And here is an example of one of the output images at 100x100 (`SizeInt = 100`):

Before you get confused as to the background colour, the image is projected onto a map where the water is a similar colour to the image.

[image: And here is an example of one of the output images at 100x100 (<code>SizeInt = 100</code>): Before you get confused as to the background colour, the image is projected onto a map where the water is a similar colour to the image.]

You can see some slight ghosting around the edges of the image.

Once it's scaled down further (to it's required scale):

[image: Once it's scaled down further (to it's required scale)]

It's almost unnoticeable...

I'm still *relatively* new to C#, but I've tried loading SVGs directly onto the map with JavaScript (`icon: "some/SVG/file.svg"`), but that causes serious performance problems, as there are up to 1,000 icons on the map at any given time, making the map unusable when using SVG files, so I have to use image files.

The images need to be sharp and not blurred around the edges. Here is the code used to generate the images, forgive any sloppy code, I'm still somewhat new to C#:

Here is the code used to scale the image:

The image needs to be rotated in a full circle (rounded to 5 degrees), hence the loop from 0 to 361.

```
private void BuildIcons(string dir)
    {

        int SizeInt = 30;

        // Get the content path
        var ContentPath = dir;

        // Get the original image
        Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(ContentPath + "base.png");

        #region Resize image

        // New size
        Size size = new Size(SizeInt, SizeInt);

        // New height/width temp vars
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;

        // Aspect ratio preservation
        int originalWidth = OriginalImage.Width;
        int originalHeight = OriginalImage.Height;

        float percentWidth = (float)size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
        float percentHeight = (float)size.Height / (float)originalHeight;

        float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;

        newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
        newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);

        // Generate the new image
        Image ResizedImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(ResizedImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsHandle.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        #endregion

        int maxside = SizeInt;

        #region Image rotation

        // Generate images
        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i += 5)
        {
            // New empty bitmap to hold rotated images
            Bitmap ReturnBitmap = new Bitmap(maxside, maxside);

            // Graphics object from the empty bitmap
            // Normal
            Graphics Gfx = Graphics.FromImage(ReturnBitmap);
            Gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            Gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            Gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            // Move rotation point to center of image
            Gfx.TranslateTransform(
                (float)ResizedImage.Width / 2,
                (float)ResizedImage.Height / 2
            );

            // Rotate
            Gfx.RotateTransform(i);

            // Move image back
            Gfx.TranslateTransform(
                -(float)ResizedImage.Width / 2,
                -(float)ResizedImage.Height / 2
            );

            // draw original in image onto graphics object
            Gfx.DrawImage(ResizedImage, new Point(0, 0));

            // Save the image
            ReturnBitmap.Save(ContentPath + i.ToString() + ".png");

            // Clean up
            ReturnBitmap.Dispose();
            Gfx.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion

        // Clean up
        ResizedImage.Dispose();
        OriginalImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is, instead, using an image editing software which works much better.

Comment: Try setting the graphics `Composi6tingMode` property to `Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy` the default is `SourceOver` and that may be causing some blurring.

Comment: @skyoxZ, I would, but I have to rotate this image 73 (360 / 5) times and for about 60 different images. When you do the maths, that's 4,380 images. I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @TnTinMn Changing the compositing mode doesn't seem to affect anything: http://prntscr.com/ievffy